# Matrix Exponential BLAS/LAPACK

Tags: lapack, blas

I'd like to know if `BLAS` or `LAPACK` implement any function for getting the exponential of a certain **double** or **float** matrix of numbers.

So far I have not been to find any similar function.

Comment: I believe that the reason you haven't found the function you are looking for is that neither of those libraries provides it off-the-shelf.

Comment: I've read something about using `Schur` decomposition or `Eigen` decomposition, but I am not working on a square matrix, but on a uni-dimensional vector.

Comment: @fpe: the usual matrix exponential doesn't make any sense applied to a vector.  It would be helpful if you described entrywise the operation you actually want to perform.

Comment: @fpe any update? did you find any function?